# React POST data to ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, reactjs

I'm using the React template when creating a new project in `Visual Studio`. It has something like this for `GET` request:

```
  fetch('api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
    });
```

I'm learning how to do a `POST` request, so I modified the code to:

```
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('values', this.state.values);

  fetch('api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
  }).then(response => response.json())
```

But not sure how to retrieve the `formData` on `ASP.Net`:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public string WeatherForecasts()
{
  // How to print out the values from formData here
  // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Request.Form.ToString());

  return "Hello";
}
```

Edit: I also don't know how to return a `Json` result from `ASP.Net`:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public JsonResult WeatherForecasts()
{
  // How to print out the values from formData here
  // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Request.Form.ToString());

  // How to return a Json here
  // return {hello: 'Hello'};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer presumes that your `this.state.values` property contains a string for testing purposes only just like the following:

```
this.setState({
  values: 'testingtext' 
});
```

I guess you are on the right track, from front-end side I assume the data is being sent. You can additionally check in the browser's network tab how the data has been passed in the HTTP request's body.

I would modify the `WeatherForcecasts()` action as the following to capture the data on the back-end side:

```
[HttpPost]
public string WeatherForecasts([FromBody] string values)
{
  // here you can check what has been passed to the values variable

  return values;
}
```

About `[FromBody]` why you need to include into the attribute:

> By default, Web API tries to get simple types from the request URI. The FromBody attribute tells Web API to read the value from the request body.

Source: [Sending Simple Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1#sending-simple-types)

If you want to override the action name in your route then you can achieve that by adding into your method the `[ActionName("YOUR_NEW_ACTION_NAME")]` attribute but it is not a mandatory one:

> You can override the action name by using the [ActionName] attribute.

Source: [Routing by Action Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api#routing-by-action-name)

I hope this helps! I guess this gives you an idea how to proceed further.

Comment: How would I print out the `values` for testing? I tried `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(values);` but could not see it anywhere.

Comment: You can try to change the `return` statement to give back the input again, maybe that works. Just like `return values.Length.ToString();` for testing quickly.

Comment: `.then(response => response.json())` is giving me error. I think I need to `return` json or something in `WeatherForecasts`?

Comment: I have changed a bit my answer to have a simple type instead of an array, please check it as well. In your case the returned value is not JSON just a string so try with `.then(response => response.text())`.

Comment: That worked, but if I keep `string[] WeatherForecasts([FromBody] string[] values)`, what type of `response` to return in `.then(response =>`?

Comment: It depends on the `return` statement. Technically `string` represented as text that's why I suggested to use `response.text()` there. In complex type case my suggestion would be if data needs to be returned - but it is totally depending on the situation - to use `System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult` in the action's return type where you can give back `return Json(new { anything = "random value" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. Hope this helps! If the answer worked seamlessly, please consider marking as the answer for your question, thanks!